# Mongo Compass is not able to connect with hostnaame but IP Address : MongoDB not running on the provided host and port

Tags: mongodb

Using mongo compass community edition, I am able to connect to MongoDB with server's IP address `xx.xx.xx.xx` but when I try to connect to it with hostname, it throws the error :

> MongoDB not running on the provided host and port